# Change Scan Code of Keys

Tags: debian, ubuntu, keyboard, xmodmap

In Windows I use sharpkeys to remap keys. On Mac I use Karabiner Elements to remap keys.

Is there a preferably built in way to remap keys based on scan code?

The advantage of this is that VirtualBox, and remote applications like TeamViewer work correctly.

Xmodmap does not work to my knowledge do to a bug in Ubuntu(I am going to call it this) https://askubuntu.com/questions/458245/unable-to-get-xmodmap-working-after-suspend

Comment: Use [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap).

Comment: I'm pretty sure ubuntu contains xmodmap. It's in package `x11-xserver-utils`.

Comment: @IporSircer yes there is a bug https://askubuntu.com/questions/458245/unable-to-get-xmodmap-working-after-suspend

Comment: As someone who uses multiple layouts on a day-to-day basis, I regret to say I'm unaware of anything that comes even close to Karabiner in terms of usability and features. However, you *can* make `xmodmap` work in your particular case if you define custom shortcuts for layout switching that would re-apply `xmodmap` every time you switch your layout.

Comment: Could you describe in your question what remappings you would like to make? It may be possible to remap your keyboard via [hwdb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/map_scancodes_to_keycodes) in which case the layout problem will be rendered moot.

Comment: closest question that I think might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344592/can-i-give-two-keyboards-different-layouts